# PHP - edit record

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

I'd like to recall a record from mysql DB in order to modify it.
I've written two PHP files:
- tabella.php = it returns a table with all the records, where a radio button allows to select a single record
- modifica.php = it should return the record selected from tabella.php

Unfortunately, I don't know how to post the record to "modifica.php" to edit it.
Any ideas?
Thanks,
alessandro

TABELLA.PHP ------------------------------------

```
    <html>
 <head>
 <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
  <title>tabella</title>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <code>
     I.I "Martini" - Mezzolombardo<br />
     a. s. 2012/2013

<h2><p align="center">consuntivo ore prof. Alessandro Vallin</p></h2>
<h4><p align="left">materia: lingua e civiltà inglese<br />monte ore settimanale: 18</p></h4>
<p align="right">
Torna alla pagina di <a href="ore.php">inserimento</a> dati.
</p>
<p align="right">
Verifica la situazione attuale: vai a vedere la <a href="somme.php">somma</a>.
</p>
<p align="left">
Le attività svolte con gli studenti (frontali) sono in <font color="#5882FA"><b>blu</b></font>.
</p>

 <?php
 $username="";
 $password="";
 $database="ore";

 mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
 @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Impossibile selezionare il database");
 $query="SELECT * FROM consuntivo ORDER BY anno,mese,giorno,ora_ini asc";
 $risultati=mysql_query($query);

 $num=mysql_numrows($risultati);

 mysql_close();
 ?>

<form action="modifica.php" method="POST"> 

<center>
<table class="sortable" border="1" cellpadding='4' cellspacing='4' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#AAAACC'>
 <tr>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#FFFF99">&#10004;</th>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#CCCC33">giorno</th>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#CCCC66">mese</th>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#CCCC99">anno</th>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#F8F8F8">inizio</th>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#F0F0F0">fine</th>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#E8E8E8">durata</th>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#99CCFF">attività</th>
 <th align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC66">categoria</th>
 </tr>

 <?php
     $i=0;
     while ($i < $num) {
         $id=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"id");
         $giorno_sett=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"giorno_sett");
         $giorno=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"giorno");
         $mese=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"mese");
         $anno=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"anno");
         $ora_ini=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"ora_ini");
         $min_ini=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"min_ini");
         $ora_fine=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"ora_fine");
         $min_fine=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"min_fine");
         $descrizione=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"descrizione");
         $categoria=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"categoria");
         $tipo=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"tipo");         
 ?>

  <tr>
     <td><font face="courier"><input type="radio" name="tick" value="<?php echo $id;?>"></font></td>
     <td><font face="courier"><?php echo $giorno_sett.$giorno;?></font></td>
     <td><font face="courier"><?php echo $mese;?></font></td>
     <td><font face="courier"><?php echo $anno;?></font></td>
     <td><font face="courier"><?php echo $ora_ini.".".$min_ini;?></font></td>
     <td><font face="courier"><?php echo $ora_fine.".".$min_fine;?></font></td>
     <td><font face="courier"><?php echo number_format((((($ora_fine*60)+($min_fine))-(($ora_ini*60)+($min_ini)))/60), 2);?></font></td>
     <td><font face="courier">
        <?php
        {
if ($tipo == 'f')
echo "<font color=\"#5882FA\"><b>$descrizione</b></font>";
else
echo "<font color=\"#000000\">$descrizione</font>";
}
        ?>
     </font></td>
     <td><font face="courier"><?php echo $categoria;?></font></td>
  </tr>

 <?php 
 $i++; 
 } 
 ?>

</table>

<p align="right">
<input type="submit" name="visualizza" value="vedi dati da modificare" />
</form>

</code>
 </body>
</html>
```

MODIFICA.PHP ------------------------------------

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
  <title>modifica</title>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
 <code>
     I.I "Martini" - Mezzolombardo<br />
     a. s. 2012/2013

<h2><p align="center">modifica dati</p></h2>
<h4><p align="left">materia: lingua e civiltà inglese<br />monte ore settimanale: 18</p></h4>
<p align="right">
Torna alla pagina di <a href="ore.php">inserimento</a> dati.
</p>
<p align="right">
Verifica la situazione attuale: vai a vedere la <a href="somme.php">somma</a>.
</p>

 <?php
$username="";
 $password="";
 $database="ore";

 mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
 @mysql_select_db($database) or die("Impossibile selezionare il database");
 $query="SELECT * FROM consuntivo WHERE id='2'";
 $risultati=mysql_query($query);

 $num=mysql_numrows($risultati);

 mysql_close();
 ?>

  <?php
     $i=0;
     while ($i < $num) {
         $id=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"id");
         $giorno_sett=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"giorno_sett");
         $giorno=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"giorno");
         $mese=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"mese");
         $anno=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"anno");
         $ora_ini=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"ora_ini");
         $min_ini=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"min_ini");
         $ora_fine=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"ora_fine");
         $min_fine=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"min_fine");
         $descrizione=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"descrizione");
         $categoria=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"categoria");
         $tipo=mysql_result($risultati,$i,"tipo");         
 ?>

 <?php echo $giorno_sett.$giorno;?>

  <?php 
 $i++; 
 } 
 ?>

 </code>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tabela.php:

```
<a href="modifica.php?id=$id_from_database">$text_from_database</a>
```

modifica.php:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

$data = fetch_from_database($id);

display_form($data);
```